# Add input identifier to logging for logstash in docker

Tags: logstash, log4j2

I have an http_poller plugin with multiple URLs and a single output to elasticsearch in my logstash pipeline. I also have a custom log4j2.properties file (with nothing custom in it yet). The issue I have is that when the output.elasticsearch fails, the logging is not giving me enough context of which input url is the cause.
So a couple questions:

- how would I add a field from the object into the logging? I have seen use of `%notEmpty{[%X{pipeline.id}]}` but don't know how to use a field from the document in the pipeline.
- how would I add a field per url in the http_poller plugin that could be added to the logging from the output plugin?

```
input {
    http_poller {
        id => "medium-pull"
        urls => {
            url1 => {               
                method => post
                url => "${ROOT}/endpoint1"
                body => '{"ids": [],  "limit": 10000,  "page": 1}'
            }

            url2 => {               
                method => post
                url => "${ROOT}/endpoint2"
                body => '{"ids": [],  "limit": 10000,  "page": 1}'
            }
```

Example error log:

```
logstash-pull1   | [2021-07-22T14:11:35,112][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main][elasticsearch]  
Could not index event to Elasticsearch. 
{:status=>404, :action=>["index", {:_id=>"%{id}", :_index=>"prefix-%{objectType}", :routing=>nil, :_type=>"_doc"}, 
#<LogStash::Event:0x77f611be>], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"prefix-%{objectType}", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"%{id}", "status"=>404, "error"=>{"type"=>"index_not_found_exception", "reason"=>"no such index [prefix-%{objectType}] and [action.auto_create_index] ([\".security*,.monitoring*,.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history*,.ml*\"]) doesn't match", "index_uuid"=>"_na_", "index"=>"prefix-%{objectType}"}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

generally it should print "name" => "url" in the output event with the configuration you already have. With that, you should be able to identify which `url` had issues etc.

Another way is have two `http_pollers` with different `id`s for example

```
input {
    http_poller {
        id => "medium-pull"
        urls => {
            url1 => {               
                method => post
                url => "${ROOT}/endpoint1"
                body => '{"ids": [],  "limit": 10000,  "page": 1}'
            }
          }
        }

    http_poller {
       id => "large_pull"
       urls => {
            url2 => {               
                method => post
                url => "${ROOT}/endpoint2"
                body => '{"ids": [],  "limit": 10000,  "page": 1}'
            }
         }
      }

    }
```

I am sure you might have looked at this document already but just in case if you have not https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http_poller.html

Comment: See update with example log. Issue I believe is that the error is happening in the output plugin not the http_poller plugin so seems like the URL context has been lost. I will look at the link about for any clues but I believe I have already.